# show a nested Json on EXT.dataview.List

Tags: javascript, json, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I was not able to show `<div>{lat}, {lon}, {ele}</div>` on a sencha touch using`EXT.dataview.List` ItemTpl with data from a Json File:

**Json:**

```
{
    "data": {
            "trackData": 
                [
                    {
                        "lon": 9.979255199432373,
                        "lat": 53.56595538391044,
                        "ele": 19
                    },
                    {
                        "lon": 9.973998069763184,
                        "lat": 53.56923037464335,
                        "ele": 15
                    }
            ]
        }
    }
```

**Model:**

```
Ext.define('Fahrradtour.model.Location', {    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',


        config: {
            fields: [
                {
                    name: 'lat',
                    type: 'float'
                },
                {
                    name: 'lon',
                    type: 'float'
                },
                {
                    name: 'ele',
                    type: 'float'
                }
            ]
        }
    });
```

**Store:**

```
Ext.define('Fahrradtour.store.LocationStore', {    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',


        requires: [
            'Fahrradtour.model.Location'
        ],


        config: {
            autoLoad: true,
            model: 'Fahrradtour.model.Location',
            storeId: 'LocationStore',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: './data/json-track.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'data',
                    record: 'trackData'
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

the Store loads his data in Architect well, but the List shows nothing.
anybody has an Idea what is wrong?
thanks.

Comment: Could you post the code of your list?

Comment: try setting rootProperty: 'data.trackData'  and remove record: 'trackData'

Comment: The problem is likely in your List config, can you post that? Also I sometimes forget to set layout : 'fit'. See it that helps.